# Terminate specific instance in AWS Spot Fleet

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

What is the best practice to terminate a specific instance in a spot fleet without replacing it with a new one ?
For Autoscaling group there is [this command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group.html). Is there a similar option for spot fleets ?

Comment: Would be nice to have an `amazon-spot-fleet` tag for this and other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented the following approach:

1. [modify-spot-fleet-request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-spot-fleet-request.html) with
   `--excess-capacity-termination-policy noTermination`
2. [describe-spot-fleet-requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-spot-fleet-requests.html) by spot fleet id and wait until `SpotFleetRequestState` changes from `modifying` to `active`
3. [terminate-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html) by instance id
4. Restore excess-capacity-termination-policy to 'default'

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late, but I found another solution for this question.

1. [`cancel_spot_instance_requests()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.cancel_spot_instance_requests())
2. [`terminate_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.terminate_instances()) by instance id
3. `modify_spot_fleet_request()` to reduce the target capacity

In this solution, we can terminate instance immediately without waiting.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.  You are much more likely to be downvoted if you do not provide more information.  Also, this question was asked 3 years ago and has an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! I know that the answer has already been accepted. I posted it because I thought it would help another person who's going through it. I apologize if it was insufficient.